# Array List increases in size when an exit command is called, not sure why

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, nullpointerexception

```
int numCoursesLeft= courseCountCalculator(grade);
System.out.println("You have " + numCoursesLeft + " course slots left. Press enter after each entry.");
String sentinel = "EXIT";
System.out.println("If at any time you run out of desired courses, type 'EXIT'");
x = !(current.equals(sentinel));
int desiredCourseCounter = 0;
while ((desiredCourseCounter <= numCoursesLeft) && x)
{
  String current = scan.nextLine();
  boolean x = !(current.equals(sentinel));
  if(x)
  {
      Course y = map.get(current);
      desiredCourseCounter++;
      desired.add(0,y); 
  }
}
```

The `courseCountCalculator(int grade)` method works and returns the correct number.
Scanner "`scan`" has been instantiated correctly and works fine.
"Course" object works and is part of a functional class.
Hash Map containing course name as a string, and course as an object, works fine.
Array List desired was previously created, instantiated, and remained empty.

For some reason, when this is called upon later in the program, a null point exception is called. I tested it by printing a `desired.size();` within the loop, and the number always appears to be off by one. I tried counteracting this by adding at position 0, but that did not solve the problem. It works fine when the user just enters `EXIT`, but if a course name is entered first, then `EXIT` is typed, the exception is thrown.

Is there something wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

One possible source of NullPointerException in your code is the line `Course y = map.get(current);`. If map doesn't contain `current`, then you'll be adding `null` to the list.

Also, unrelated to your problem, you probably meant to use `<` instead of `<=` in condition of while loop.

I advice you to learn to use the debugger and look how variables change line by line. Usually it helps to make everything clear in cases like this.

Comment: I'm certain that the inputs are in the map.
Thanks for the catch with the equal sign though.